# Microsoft Office Word 2010: How to "Find and Replace" an entire line using "regular expressions" (wildcards)?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, regex, wildcards

I would like to ***"Find and Replace"* entire lines in Microsoft Office Word 2010** which match some criteria.

I tried to find the solution in the official documentation, but I didn't find the answer:

- [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx)
- [Add power to Word searches with regular expressions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/add-power-to-word-searches-with-regular-expressions-HA001087305.aspx)

(btw. here are two more useful unofficial documents: [Find and Replace using wildcards](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm); [Regular Expressions in Microsoft Word](http://books.google.hu/books?id=587w6j5vPIQC&lpg=PA253&ots=0rphXJDfc6&dq=regular%20expressions%20in%20microsoft%20word&hl=hu&pg=PA253#v=onepage&q=regular%20expressions%20in%20microsoft%20word&f=false))

---

### Example

For example: I would like to search for all the lines which have the *"Heading 2"* style, and replace them so that they get between `##` symbols: so this is the original text: `This is my title`, and I would like to find it and replace it this way: `## This is my title ##` (this way I could transform a text's title into a Wiki-compatible heading 2 without any external plugins <sub>(EDIT: sorry, in the meantime I realized the MediaWiki-compatible heading 2 style uses `==` instead of `##`, but it doesn't change the main point)</sub>).

So after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, checking "**Use wildcards**", selecting Format > Style > Heading 2, I've tried this and it did NOT work: `(*^13>)` or `(<*^13>)`, where `^13` matches *"Paragraph break / 'carriage' return"* (see [this](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)) - this made Word search madly, and the GUI got frozen for minutes (!). At the end, it didn't find anything (but I DO have texts with Heading 2 style).

[image: Microsoft Word 2010 - Find and Replace (*^13>) - Not Responding (Use Wildcards checked)]

OK, this is not the appropriate pattern, so what would be the appropriate way to search and replace entire lines in Word?

Comment: This would be sooooo much easier if Microsoft found out about this new thing called "regex."    For that matter, just adding a "start of line" option to their special things list would be a big help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but for some reason I wasn't able to do this in a single search/replace operation:

### Steps

1. **Before**:

   [image: 1]
2. **Replace empty string (format *Heading 2*) with "## ^& ##" (no formatting)**:

   [image: 2]
3. **After first replace**:

   [image: 3]
4. **Replace "^p ##" (no formatting) with " ##^p" (no formatting)** (be aware that there is a space at the beginning of the replace string!):

   [image: 4]
5. **After second replace**:

   [image: 5]

Comment: Thanks,this really solves it, with one exception: if I have multiple headers of the same kind after each other, like this: http://i.imgur.com/tJSFXT2.png; after [Find and Replace](http://i.imgur.com/uM70WiN.png) (sorry, I forgot that in MediaWiki, for parsing headers, I must use `==` symbols instead of `##` symbols, but this doesn't change the main point), Word places `==` symbols like this: http://i.imgur.com/aHABiBF.png, and after the [2nd replace](http://i.imgur.com/fLWpWwO.png), like this: http://i.imgur.com/HkBGRib.png, which means I have to put an empty line between each of them first!:)

Comment: But I could solve my problem with your solution, so thanks, +1 and accepted! ;) This new line "bug" (?) you mentioned is really strange though.

Comment: It seems the ^p at the end of the line is part of the text with style Heading 2. So when you attempt to replace `Heading Text` with `## <Search String> ##`, what actually happens is that `Heading Text^p` is replaced with `## Heading Text^p ##`. Thus the trailing ## ends up on the next line preceded with a space. I don't know how to restrict the search string from including the trailing ^p.

Comment: Yes, this can be the reason, thank you. It would be really good to know how to restrict the search and replace to exclude the newline character. Anyway, you solved it. :)

Answer (score -1):

I know the question is old, but not finding any practical solutions here or other places, I thought I'd post the answer for posterity's sake.

Perhaps Word has made enhancements to the function that allowed me to perform a single replace operation that did the job the asker described:

Find What: **(*{1,})**

---Style: **Heading 1**

Replace With: **\1**

---Style: **Normal**

Note that using (*) instead of (*{1,}) eliminated the first character in the line. Apparently, there's some special meaning involved in (*) that I'm not inclined to research.

Comment: Didn't work for me using Word 2013 - I enabled "Use wildcards" and made "Replace with:" `## \1 ##`, and the result was `## H #### e #### a #### d #### i #### n #### g ####`. With your answer as written with "Use wildcards" checked, it just says "All done, we made xx replacements", but doesn't change any text - obviously because your "Replace with" is just replacing with the entire text to find, so doesn't do anything.